# double bool array isn't working in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written the following code in c++. I initialize a double bool array and each element in the double array to FALSE but when I check in an if-statement it prints out "good" even though everything is false. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x,y;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    bool** check = new bool*[y];
    for(int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
    check[i] = new bool[x];
    *check[i]=false;
    }

    if(check[1][1]==true){
        cout << "good" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code could be replaced with this: `std::vector<std::vector<bool>> check(x, std::vector<bool>(y, false));`  Then you don't have the memory leak at the end of the function, and the rest of the code stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*check[i]=false;`, you're setting only the 1st element of `check[i]` (i.e. `check[i][0]`) to false. You need an inner loop to set every element, such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
    check[i] = new bool[x];
    for (int j = 0; j < x; ++j) {
        check[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*check[i]=false;
```

Sets only `check[i][0]` to `false`. `checks[i][1]` - `checks[i][x-1]` remain uninitialized.

If you want to set all the elements of `check` to `false`, you need to use something along the lines of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
   check[i] = new bool[x];
   for(int j = 0; j < x; ++j )
   {
      check[i][j]=false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
  int x,y;
  cin >> x;
  cin >> y;
  bool check[][] = new bool[x][y];
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      check[i][j] = false;
    }
  }
  if(check[1][1]){
    cout << "good" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

or you can also replace the (invalid) line `*check[i]=false;` with `memset(check[i],0,sizeof(bool)*x)`

Comment: it has to be dynamic though since the size parameters are determined in runtime :/ ... I want my code to work with keeping it dynamic